# Global footnote on same page in tcolorbox or minipage environment

Tags: footnotes, tcolorbox, minipage

If I have a breakable tcolorbox (or a similar minipage) environment and I want to use a global (bottom of page) footnote, the standard practice is to use **\footnotemark**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
We quote\footnotemark
\lipsum[1-7]
\end{tcolorbox}
\footnotetext{from Lorem ipsum}
\end{document}
```

But for environments through several pages (or a small environment that just happens to be at the bottom of a page), the footnote is on a different page than the footnote label. How to fix this?

Comment: in this case you can simply put `\footnotetext[1]{from Lorem ipsum}` before the `tcolorbox` but perhaps that's cheating, getting to a middle page of a multi-page box is a bit harder.